# El uso de "can't" para traducción de "no capaz"

Tags: traducción

(Por favor, perdona - y/o corrija - mi "Google Translate" español.)

Tanto Duolingo como Google Translate traducen la frase "¡No eres capaz!" como "You are not capable!" Esto es razonable, pero nunca lo utilizaría en el lenguaje cotidiano.

Para mí, en inglés "can't" significa tanto *incapacidad* como *falta de habilidad*, mientras en español "no poder" significa el primero pero "no capaz" significa el último.  ¿"No you can't!" está bien, o debería yo atenerme estrictamente a "not capable" por "no capaz"?

Comment: ¡No eres capaz! = No you can't!, No eres capaz = You are not capable.

Comment: @mdewey Sí, tiene lógica.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*capable* es un adjetivo. Comparar:

> 1. No eres capaz. (Nos dirigimos a la persona mostrando que su cualidad para ejecutar una acción, no es posible.)
> 2. No puedes hacerlo. (Mostramos que la persona no posee la *habilidad* de ejecutar una acción.)

Todo depende en un tema de contexto, pues decir *no puedes* o *no eres capaz*, no son iguales pero la segunda alude más a denotar una cualidad de la persona que no posee, la primera se refiere a la *acción.*

Comment: Exacto, mientras que "Can" es el verbo potencia, "capaz" es el adjetivo (aunque debería ser aceptado el adjetivo de capabilidad). y aunque se pueden intercambiar en la traducción yo creo que no se debería debido a que da lugar a interpretaciones incorrectas. por que no es lo mismo "You can't because you don't have the capability" a "you can't because I won't let you"

Answer (score 1):

Para mí la relación sería:

ser capaz - to be able / to not be able to

poder - can / cannot (tanto con el sentido de "permiso" como con el sentido de "tener capacidad / habilidad para".